# The Killing form of $\mathfrak{u}(2)$ and the maximal tori of $U(2)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

On *An Introduction to Lie Groups and the Geometry of Homogeneous Spaces* by Andreas Arvanitoyeorgos I have found the following method to calculate the Killing form of various matrix Lie groups. I would have a question about it.

Take for instance the group $U(2)$. The method selects two matrixes $X$ and $Y$ $\in \mathfrak{u}(2)$ of the form $$ X=\begin{bmatrix}i \theta_1 &  0 \\\ 0 & i \theta_2 \end{bmatrix},\\ Y=\begin{bmatrix}i \phi_1 &  0 \\\ 0 & i \phi_2 \end{bmatrix} $$ and a basis for $\mathfrak{u}(2)$ given by $$e_1=\begin{bmatrix}i &  0 \\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, e_2=\begin{bmatrix}0 &  0 \\\ 0 & i \end{bmatrix}$$ $$e_3=\begin{bmatrix}0 &  1 \\\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, e_4=\begin{bmatrix}0 &  i \\\ i & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ and then evaluates the $4 \times 4$ matrixes corresponding  to the linear transformations $ad(X)$ and $ad(Y)$ on elements of $\mathfrak{u}(2)$ seen as vectors of $4$ components in the basis $(e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4)$.
I have found:

$$ad(X)e_1=[X,e_1]=0$$ $$ad(X)e_2=[X,e_2]=0$$ $$ad(X)e_3=[X, e_3]=(\theta_1-\theta_2)e_4$$ $$ad(X)e_4=[X, e_4]=(\theta_2-\theta_1)e_3$$ so $$ad(X)=\begin{bmatrix}0 &  0 & 0 & 0\\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \theta_2-\theta_1 \\\ 0 & 0 & \theta_1 -\theta_2 & 0\end{bmatrix}, ad(Y)=\begin{bmatrix}0 &  0 & 0 & 0\\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \phi_2-\phi_1 \\\ 0 & 0 & \phi_1 -\phi_2 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
and finally $$B(X,Y)=tr(ad(X) \circ ad(Y))=4tr(XY)-2trXtrY$$
So far, so good. Then the author says that the expression found for matrixes like $X$ and $Y$ is valid for all elements $\in \mathfrak{u}(2)$. This is the generalization that I don't understand. In order to explain this, in the subsequent section it is shown that the Lie group $U(2)$ has a maximal torus :
$$T_{U}=\begin{bmatrix}e^{\theta_1 i} &  0 \\\ 0 & e^{\theta_2 i} \end{bmatrix}$$ and presented as part of a theorem that for each compact connected Lie group, each element $g$ is contained in some maximal torus. The the author says that these two things alone are enough for the formula evaluated above to hold for any two elements of  $\mathfrak{u}(2)$. I don't see why.

If I understood correctly, the matrixes of the form $X$ and $Y$ generate the maximal torus $T_u$. However, I would say that we may also need the following facts:

1. any two maximal tori $T_1$ and $T_2$ are conjugate, i.e. $\exists g \in G |  gT_1g^{-1}=T_2 $
2. if $T$ is a maximal torus of $G$  with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{t}$ then $G=\bigcup_{g \in G}gTg^{-1}$ and $\mathfrak{g}=\bigcup_{g \in G}Ad(g)\mathfrak{t}$
3. the Killing form is $Ad$ invariant, i.e. $B(X, Y)=B(Ad(g)X, Ad(g)Y) \forall g \in G$ and $\forall X, Y \in \mathfrak{g}$

However, even with these additional facts, I would need $X$ and $Y$ to be simultaneously diagonalizable... or not?
Any help?

thanks!

Comment: In the formula for $B$, there should be a composition $\circ$ where you have a comma inside the trace, right? Otherwise, I understand your doubts. All the facts you mention I would grant, but I also see the problem that two general elements don't need to lie in the same maximal torus.

Comment: One could invoke the theorem that the Killing form is the unique ad-invariant bilinear form up to scaling, and check that that formula does define an ad-invariant bilinear form, and they do agree on a space with nonzero outputs, so the scaling must be right. That doesn't seem to be what the source has in mind though.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg thanks for the comments, your hints makes sense. Yes, the problem is when the two elements belong to different maximal tori. I'll amend the typo you found, have a nice day.